# How to shift x axis positions of two geoms relative to each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `ggplot` plot. I need to shift error bars relative to jittered points. My code is:

```
data("cabbages", package = "MASS")

require("ggplot2")

pos_1 <- position_jitterdodge(
    jitter.width  = 0.25,
    jitter.height = 0,
    dodge.width   = 0.9
)

gg <-
    ggplot(data = cabbages,
           aes(
               x      = Cult,
               y      = HeadWt,
               colour = Cult,
               fill   = Cult
               )) +

    geom_jitter(alpha = 0.4, position = pos_1) +

    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", size = 3) +

    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
                 geom = "errorbar",
                 width = 0.05,
                 lwd = 1,
                 fun.args = list(conf.int = 0.95)
) +

    theme_bw()

print(gg)
```

Current result is:

[image]

And I need something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may add an offset to `x` in `aes` in each`stat_summary` (`aes(x = as.numeric(Cult) + 0.2)`):

```
ggplot(data = cabbages,
       aes(x = Cult,
           y      = HeadWt,
           colour = Cult,
           fill   = Cult)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.4, position = pos_1) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = as.numeric(Cult) + 0.2), fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", size = 3) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = as.numeric(Cult) + 0.2), fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
               geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.05,
               lwd = 1,
               fun.args = list(conf.int = 0.95)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that in constructing the plot you'll need a `geom` with a categorical x-axis _before_ you add a `geom` with `x=as.numeric(factor)+0.1`. The first `geom` that you add sets the x-axis type, so if you add the `geom` with `x=as.numeric(factor)+0.1` first, then the x-axis will be continuous and you can't add a factor variable to a continuous axis (unless you first convert it using `as.numeric()`).

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can use `position_nudge()` with the same effect:

```
stat_summary(
    fun.y = "mean",
    geom = "point",
    size = 3,
    position = position_nudge(x=0.2)
) +
stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_cl_normal",
    geom = "errorbar",
    width = 0.05,
    lwd = 1,
    fun.args = list(conf.int = 0.95),
    position = position_nudge(x=0.2)
)
```

[image: result with position_nudge()]