# How to do the equivalent of "dodge" and "nudge" at the same time in ggplot2, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to shift the gray elements (the small jittered points and the violins) to the right so they don't horizontally overlap (1) the shapes marking the means (2) the error bars). I believe that position_nudge would normally work. But I am already using position_dodge, and I don't see a way to combine position_nudge with position_dodge.

See the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpl1H.png

```
year <-  c("1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th","1st","3rd","5th")  
status <-   c("P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","Q","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R")  
performance <-  c(31,54,79,44,63,86,40,61,75,40,61,80,33,63,77,40,61,81,46,70,80,35,69,83,41,57,73,48,50,82,41,68,90,45,78,84,41,71,86,58,74,97,40,77,80,60,76,95,57,74,98,48,69,82,53,68,97,50,80,86,47,70,93,45,85,87,43,81,88,59,74,106,47,85,80,65,79,99,60,81,101,58,69,86,59,73,107,57,90,88)  
tempdata <- data.frame (year, status, performance)  
library(ggplot2)  
#Establish the graph's general parameters  
ggplot(data=tempdata, aes(x=year, y=performance, linetype=status, shape=status, size=status, color=status, fill=status))+
#Plot the raw, unaveraged data  
geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.9, jitter.height=0, jitter.width=0.06), size = 3.1,color="black", fill="gray50", alpha=0.3, show.legend=FALSE) +  
#Plot a "violin"  
geom_violin(fill="gray90", color="gray78", position=position_dodge(.9), alpha=0.1, size=0.9, scale="count", linetype="solid", width=.5, show.legend=FALSE) +   
#Plot the Error Bars  
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, position=position_dodge(.9),    geom="errorbar", alpha=1.0, width=0.15) +
#Plot the mean markers  
geom_point(stat = "summary", fun.y="mean", size=8.0, stroke = 2.4, alpha = 1, position=position_dodge(.9), fill=NA)+  
#Create a list of the particular colors (line colors), fills (the fill colors for shapes), line types, and sizes/thicknesses. 
scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24, 22))+  
scale_size_manual(values=c(1.2, 1.2, 1.2)) +  
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid"))+ 
scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red", "purple"))+  
labs(x="Year", y="Performance", color="Status:", size="Status:",  shape="Status:", fill="Status:", linetype="Status:")+  
theme (panel.background=element_rect(fill = NA),panel.grid.major=element_line(color = NA), axis.line=element_line(size=1, color="black"), axis.ticks=element_line(color="black", size=1),axis.ticks.length=unit(5, "mm"), axis.title.x=element_text(margin = margin(t=20, r=0, b=30, l=0)),axis.title.y=element_text(margin = margin(t=0, r=20, b=0, l=0)),legend.position="bottom",legend.key=element_rect(fill=NA, color=NA, size=0.7),legend.key.width=unit(15, "mm"), text=element_text(size=rel(6.0)),legend.title=element_text(size=rel(4.5)), legend.text=element_text(size=rel(4.5)) )
```

Comment: ___________Done

Comment: Maybe this can get you started: [How to shift x axis positions of two geoms relative to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461993/how-to-shift-x-axis-positions-of-two-geoms-relative-to-each-other)

Comment: OK! Good to hear!